# How to work google earth engine in a text editor like Visual Studio code?

Tags: npm-install, google-earth-engine

I am trying to work earth engine using a text editor like Visual studio Code. They have given a document on how to run the earth engine in the system. It is very confusing for me. The link to the document is [npm install](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/npm_install)

I tried all these in visual studio but I can't get the earth engine client library to install.

Comment: Ok, so you linked the instructions on how to do it already. which step fails for you?

Comment: 2nd step, installing earth engine client library

Comment: How can we help you if you don't tell us what your problem is? What's the problem you have? Did you get an error when calling install?

Comment: npm err! write after end is the error which is displaying, I want a proper step how I should configure the earth engine to a code editor. I don't have a background with coding, I want to do the processes of google earth engine from my text editor that is all I want to do.

Comment: why you don't use the code editor of google, that is much simpler than using npm, visual code, especially if you don't have a background in coding
https://code.earthengine.google.com/

Comment: I am working on it, I just want to know how can I really set that  in my system. I hope I could explore much more if I do away from their web code editor. If someone could provide step by step instruction I could catch easily.

Answer (score 0):

Ok.  I know this is not exactly what you ask for but it’s a workaround to use a different editor, because I was having similar issues.  I actually made a stack overflow account to explain what I’m doing.

1. In the GEE web app, make a new project and make a repository and add some files to it if you haven’t done so already
2. In the scripts tab, click on the configure tab
3. Copy the code for cloning that repository to your local machine.
4. It won’t work at first, but the error will give you a link to follow, copy the code and paste it into the command line as instructed and run it then follow the instructions that come when it doesn’t work.
5. Clone the repository after you’ve followed googles instructions
6. Open the folder and files in the editor of your choice
7. Edit to your hearts content in whatever editor you want and save
8. Git add the files you want to push
9. Push them back to Google
10. Run the script in the Google Earth Engine webapp.

I know it’s not exactly what you want, you still have to use the webapp (for now, I’ll explore more stuff in the coming weeks) but my whole reason for this was wanting to edit locally conveniently and not use their editor because it doesn’t have a nice theme.  Anyway, good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You can go through the instructions of the following website:

https://eodatascience.com/Newsroom/Technical-blog-Managing-Google-Earth-Engine-repos

It shows:

1. The process of cloning git of google earth repository.
2. edit them in local editor;
3. finally push them back to earth engine

Comment: Instead of posting a link try to address the question then put the link as a reference for details.